# Is it possible to get values for 2 parameters from the another dropdown parameter on separate occasions in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a parameter 'Select'(with two values). Based on the value of 'Select' parameter I'm passing list of values to 'Source' parameter from Stored Procedures. I need to pass the selected value from 'Source' to another parameter 'Dest1'. Post that I need the user to be able to select value from the dropdowns('Select' and 'Source') again, and this time the value should be passed to the parameter 'Dest2'.Basically the user  should be able to select the value dynamically for both the parameters 'Dest1' and 'Dest2' from the same 'Source' and 'Select' Parameters. Is this possible in SSRS?

Your answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This won't work. Why you are not using only two parameters, each with its own source(dataset)?

Comment: Actually I'm rewriting the reports to SSRS. I tried to replicate the existing report. Seems like it is not possible. I'm going to follow a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the short answer is no.

Parameters which rely on other parameters have to be in order. You cannot reference a value from you 3rd parameter (for example) in your first as that would create a loop.

The only way you could to this is to repeat the parameters `Select` and `Source` as `Select2` and `Source2` so that the workflow thru parameter selections are in one direction.

`Select` then `Source` then `Dest1` then `Select2` then `Source2` then `Dest2`

If this does not answer you question sketch the workflow out so its easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm going to follow this approach.